# Mono C#: mkbundle'd "Hello World" script executes with only the exit code "11" on a web server

Tags: c#, unix, mono, mkbundle

I'd like to run Mono(C#) code on a Web server that does not have Mono Runtime installed. Since mkbundle is able to produce native code, I am first trying to get a plain "Hello World" script to work on both sides, which runs locally but not on the Web server.

C# HelloWorld.cs script:

```cs
 using System;

 public class HelloWorld
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
       System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
 }
```

I do compiling and bundling using:
$ gmcs HelloWorld.cs -out:HelloWorld.exe
$ mkbundle -o helloworld HelloWorld.exe --static --deps

My only permitted way to execute this script on the web server is by using a PHP script, which has the following:

```php
 $cmd = "./helloworld";
 exec($cmd, $array, $return_code);
 var_dump($array);
 //passthru($cmd, $return_code);
 var_dump($return_code);
```

Locally, this script works and I get the following response:

> array(1) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(13) "Hello, World!"
>   }
>   int(0)

But on the web server this is all the script returns

> array(0) { } int(11)

Bash exit code 11 is non-standard according to [this](http://en.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) and [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) exit codelists.

Both machines are on a 64bit Linux and a "file helloworld" returns the following...
On Local machine:

> helloworld: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=fbc9731fb13202c604b025ba3eefe51c69dc40d8, not stripped

On Web server:

> helloworld: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

Might "dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped" still mean that some embedded libraries or mono runtime be still missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a virtual machine with the same OS as the Web Server, when running the bundle I got 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)', which has the exit code '11'. mkbundle is not a fully compatible way to deploy Mono written software on Linux machines.

So in the end I installed Mono on the virtual machine, compiled and mkbundle'd the code, and after uploading the file to the Web Server it was able to execute it.